# Auto turn off switch for android phone according to battery status

Tags: root-access

Looking for any switch with Bluetooth connectivity with mobile and auto turn off power to mobile charger according to battery barfing status. Would be great help for charging overnight. If it comes with alarm after full charging, even better, like i can charge my mobile while cooking without worrying to turn off after full charge.

Answer (score 0):

Tasker is exactly what you need.

You can do lots of automation with tasker. App is a bit hard to understand but when you figured it out it has the power of freedom.

[Tasker Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)

Comment: More details on *Tasker* are to be found in our [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) by the way ;)

Comment: Wow didnt know that wiki page thanks for comment :)

Comment: Many of our tags have a corresponding wiki page with useful details, first-aid, and more – always worth a look :) Also worth seeing: My collection of [Tasker Resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) :)

Comment: That's an hell of an automation :D

Comment: Indeed. Especially when you consider even that collection is far from being complete :)

Comment: You didn't do that list manually right? please say no

Comment: In fact I did. Just the app ratings are *updating* automatically. // Btw: We're getting off-topic here with our comments. I'd recommend you add a few more details in your answer (a "raw example" *how* to accomplish what the OP wants – e.g. a profile-outline) so I can upvote it, then we can meet in chat ;)